# Invalid bind expression type of Datetime for column of type Date

Tags: apex, soql, datetime, date

```
for(Sample_Limit_vod__c SL : [select Account_vod__c,
                                     Product_vod__c,
                                     Disbursed_Quantity_vod__c,
                                     Start_Date_vod__c,
                                     End_Date_vod__c 
                              from   Sample_Limit_vod__c 
                              where  Account_vod__c= :srt.ABV_Account__c 
                              and    Product_vod__c=: srt.ABV_BRC__c 
                              and    Start_Date_vod__c<= :srt.ABV_Date_of_Request__c 
                              and    End_Date_vod__c>= :srt.ABV_Date_of_Request__c ] )
{
    SL.Disbursed_Quantity_vod__c = SL.Disbursed_Quantity_vod__c - (srt.ABV_Requested_Quantity__c - srt.ABV_Approved_Quantity__c);
    updSL.add(SL);
}
```

I have this pieceof code, where i need to compare `Start_date_vod__C`(a date field) with `ABV_Date_of_Request__c` (a datetime field) in the SOQL query and it is giving incompatible error. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Start_Date_vod__c <= :srt.ABV_Date_of_Request__c.Date()
```

Should work for you.